# Batch Pasting Data into Access Form

Tags: ms-access

Our lab is currently copying and pasting data from equipment reports into Excel.  The copy/paste part is ok - less manual data entry.  However, I want to shift this to an Access Form, but as far as I can tell there's no way to paste a row of data into a set of textboxes into an Access form.  My experience so far has been that Access concatenates the copied Excel row data into one long string and puts it all into the first textbox.  Any ideas how to get Access to recognize the textboxes as paste-able?  I don't want the users pasting directly into a table - I want to manipulate and clean the data first.

Comment: If the copied columns match the form columns (not sure if visible controls or recordsource columns), then Paste should work. Users must select the (empty) record first.

Comment: You could try to automate this. A macro could move the data from the selected row in Excel to the Access form, and a hotkey/button in Excel could be bound to that macro. That way, you avoid any copy-paste errors.

Comment: 1) Create a separate table for temporarily pasting the data, then clean and copy into your permanent table.  2) Erik's suggestion is good for going from Excel to Access, but what about getting the data directly from the equipment reports to start with?  What format are the equipment reports in?

Comment: Andre - I think you are talking about pasting into a table - right?  I'm trying to paste into a Form instead - I feel that pasting into the main table is too dangerous.  Erik and C Perkins - those are not bad ideas - thanks.  I wish there was a more user-friendly way though.

Comment: It's possible to create a form as a Datasheet view that is bound to a table or any updatable query.  (Actually, the datasheet view may not be required, but seems a good conceptual match for pasting tabular data.)  Pasting tabular data should work the same as if you had the table or query open directly, but it'll be in a form of your making...